# Как извлечь данные из LineEdit спомощью ObjectName? Python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, gui, qlineedit

У меня есть переменная с **`ObjectName`** - `self.fio_edit_set_2_obj`.

Как мне узнать ведённые в неё данные благодаря `objectname`?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Поймите правильно, если вы не предоставляете минимально-воспроизводимый пример, то не совсем понятно, чем вам можно помочь.

А если так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.fio_edit_set_2_obj = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.fio_edit_set_2_obj.textChanged.connect(self.text_changed)
        self.fio_edit_set_2_obj.setPlaceholderText('Введите ФИО')
        
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)

        layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        layout.addRow('Введите ФИО', self.fio_edit_set_2_obj)
        layout.addRow('Проверьте ввод -->', self.btn)
        
    def text_changed(self, text): 
        pass

    def btn_clicked(self): 
        print(f'fio_edit_set_2_obj.text: `{self.fio_edit_set_2_obj.text()}`') #
       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мне нужно именно с nameobject